# FileName not showing in FileDialog

Tags: java, swt

I am using the [FileDialog](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FileDialog.html) class to ask a user to choose a file.
The issue I am encountering is that while I set the file name for the user, it doesn't show up in the dialog. 
Is it a limitation of Cinnamon ? If I run this code on Windows, it works:

```
    final FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(activeShell, SWT.OPEN);
    dialog.setText("Choose a file");
    dialog.setFilterPath("/home/frederic/Videos");
    dialog.open()
```

[image]

I am on the following environment :
Debian 9

Cinnamon 3.2.7

openjdk version "1.8.0_212"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b01-1~deb9u1-b01)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Does the given filename exist?

Comment: Yes, the filename exists

Answer (score 1):

`setFileName` takes a file name parameter **not** a path. So

```
dialog.setFileName("doc.txt");
```

You use `dialog.setFilterPath` to set the initial directory path.

```
dialog.setFilterPath("/home/frederic/Documents");
```

Comment: See my updated question, I've tried with SetFilterPath with the same result

Comment: setFilterPath is the path of a **directory**

Comment: Nice catch but it doesn't work either with this : dialog.setFilterPath("/home/frederic/Documents");

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my hunch was right and that this issue has nothing to do with the [FileDialog](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FileDialog.html) class but more with the desktop environment I am using (Cinnamon).

In order to show the path in the FileDialog, the key combination Ctr+L will make it appear ([Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170038/cinnamon-how-to-get-path-in-text-on-gui-window-and-how-to-open-terminal-at-cur))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Mac. I had to change the FileDialog to use SWT.SAVE rather than SWT.OPEN and it worked. That might or might not be a reasonable solution depending on your use case